# convert String to array in javascript "datastatusMonthly[0]"

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

`datastatusMonthly[0]`  - This is my String in javascript
If i print this, it is printing as same string.

How do i get the value of '0' index in array `datastatusMonthly` using this above string?

Any help please?

Comment: Don't use a string? Please include some indication of how you're using this code, where it comes from, etc. Context will help determine the best option to use.

Comment: Do you want the answer to work for only that specific string?  A string in the form datastatusMonthly[#] where # could be any number?  could the array have multiple entries?  ie datastatusMonthly[#, #, #].  Please be a little more specific about the possible range of inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution without eval, which is [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea), using regex with group:

```js
var datastatusMonthly = [3];

var text = 'datastatusMonthly[0]';
var regex = /(datastatusMonthly)\[([0-9]+)\]/g;
var match = regex.exec(text);

var arrayName = match[1];
var arrayIndex = match[2];

console.log(window[arrayName][arrayIndex]);
```

Comment: this works and even 'eval' also works correctly, but i not understood why 'eval' is evil.

Comment: There are tons of reasons. See the answers for that post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: The biggest one might be performance! The solution with `eval` is slower than that one I gave, but there are also a lot of security issues

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval`. The eval function will evaluate your string. JS bin here https://jsbin.com/guqoqukoqa/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

This dose't have to be in a String i guess. correct me if i am not understanding it properly 

`var fistElement = datastatusMonthly[0];`

This link might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements

Comment: var firstElement = "datastatusMonthly[0]" , this is the string